# How to optimally shuffle a very large deck of cards?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

This might be an ill-posed question, but it came up when I was playing a game that requires shuffling a very large ($n \gg 52$) deck of cards.

I can't comfortably shuffle more than 60-70 cards at a time, so to mix all the cards evenly I ended up doing the following:

- Divide the deck up into $\lceil n/m \rceil$ piles
- Riffle shuffle each pile twice
- Swap half of each once-shuffled pile with half of another pile
- Re-shuffle each pile twice
- Put the entire deck of $n$ cards back together

But I got the feeling that this can't possibly be the most efficient way to do this.

**Question:** Assuming we are only able to simultaneously shuffle (riffle or otherwise) $m$ cards where $m \ll n$, what's the most efficient way to shuffle the entire deck? Is there any existing literature on this?

Comment: Generally speaking... when it comes to shuffling cards, Persi Diaconis is your friend.

Comment: I'm aware of his work! Maybe I should put the question to him directly...

Comment: As I recall, it takes about 7 riffle shuffles to truly randomize a standard 52-card deck, so your 4-shuffle technique for a larger deck is falling well-short of randomization.

Comment: David Aldous, Persi Diaconis, [Shuffling cards and stopping times](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/aldous86.pdf), The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 93, No. 5, pp. 333–348, Mathematical Association of America, 1986.

Comment: Dave Bayer, Persi Diaconis, [Trailing the dovetail shuffle to its lair](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1177005705), The Annals of Applied Probability, Vol. 2, No. 2, pp. 294-313, May 1992.

Comment: There are mechanical shufflers available that seem capable of handling several decks.  Caveat: I haven't tried any myself.

Comment: @awkward - I have. Maybe a high quality one would work well, but the ones I've used tend to grab many cards from one side at a time, and as a result give a mediocre shuffle at best.

Comment: Just following up here, I don't think any of those papers linked above are relevant, because I think they assume the ability to shuffle arbitrarily large decks at once. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: Papers that are relevant may cite those two.